# I'm trying to switch to Visual Studio Code but keep getting an "ENOENTBuild finished with error(s)" message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>



void sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

Starting build...
C:\usr\bin\cpp -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\19494\Desktop\CPlusPlus\leetcode.cpp -o C:\Users\19494\Desktop\CPlusPlus\leetcode.exe
spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENTBuild finished with error(s).

And this is my json properties file:
(I just changed this to put mingw as compiler and in includePath. I include it because I think its probable the error is related to it.)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\opt\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After hours I have got it to work. If anyone else has this problem what I did was added gdb.exe to my bin folder (there was none before), deleted Visual Studio Code and all files related to it, and re-added the path to my compiler/bin to environment variables. I restarted my computer and it runs now.